# How to extend AbstractTransactionAspect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspect

I extend `AbstractTransactionAspect` as follow:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class ProsperTransactionAspect
        extends AbstractTransactionAspect {
    public ProsperTransactionAspect() {
        super(new AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource() {
            @NotNull
            @Override
            protected TransactionAttribute findTransactionAttribute(@NotNull Method method) {
                return new MyDefaultTransactionAttribute();
            }

            @NotNull
            @Override
            protected TransactionAttribute findTransactionAttribute(@NotNull Class<?> clazz) {
                return new MyDefaultTransactionAttribute();
            }
        });
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    private void anyPublicOperation(){};

    @Pointcut("within(com.katalisindonesia.prosper.facade..*) || bean(*Service)")
    private void inFacade(){};

    @Pointcut("anyPublicOperation() && inFacade() && args(txObject)")
    protected void transactionalMethodExecution(Object txObject){};

}
```

However, spring boot gives me this: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting to find 3 arguments to bind by name in advice, but actually found 2 arguments.`

**Can anybody spot my mistake? Thank you.**

Complete stack trace:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting to find 3 arguments to bind by name in advice, but actually found 2 arguments.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:138) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:751) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:387) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at com.katalisindonesia.prosper.web2.ProsperWeb2Application.main(ProsperWeb2Application.java:126) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting to find 3 arguments to bind by name in advice, but actually found 2 arguments.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:497) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:94) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:107) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:254) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1063) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1036) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:833) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:428) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:391) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:385) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:200) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:176) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:150) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting to find 3 arguments to bind by name in advice, but actually found 2 arguments.
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.bindExplicitArguments(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:477) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.bindArgumentsByName(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:443) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.calculateArgumentBindings(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:394) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvice(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:295) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.InstantiationModelAwarePointcutAdvisorImpl.instantiateAdvice(InstantiationModelAwarePointcutAdvisorImpl.java:167) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.InstantiationModelAwarePointcutAdvisorImpl.<init>(InstantiationModelAwarePointcutAdvisorImpl.java:113) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvisor(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:199) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvisors(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:127) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.buildAspectJAdvisors(BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.java:110) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:254) ~[spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1063) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1036) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```